# Writing Regular Expressions to a file Python

Tags: python, regex

For a project I have to extract the color data which is defined in an IFC file.
IFC defines an EXPRESS based entity-relationship model consisting of several hundred entities organized into an object-based inheritance hierarchy.

Section of an IFC file for as an example:

```
#3510= IFCCLOSEDSHELL((#3392,#3410,#3421,#3440,#3451,#3462,#3473,#3484,#3495,#3506));
#3514= IFCFACETEDBREP(#3510);
#3517= IFCCOLOURRGB($,0.9372549,0.79215686,0.44705882)
```

Now I want to achieve returning all colour data using Regular Expressions in Python.
So far I came up with this (I am new to programming)

## opens ifc file

```
IfcFile = open('ifc2.ifc', 'r')

#defines the string 
IfcColourData = re.compile('ifccolourrgb', re.IGNORECASE)


#iterating over the ifc file
for RadColourData in IfcFile:
    if re.search(IfcColourData, RadColourData):
        print(RadColourData)
IfcFile.close()       

#writing the  data to a file
f = open('IFC2RAD.txt', 'w')
f.write(RadColourData)
f.close()
```

The code works, it returns all the lines in the ifcfile with IfcColourRGB in them. (What I can see in my console). I am using Eclipse with Pydev and Python 3.4.

Only when I want to write the result of RadColourData to a file called IFC2RAD.txt it only writes the last line of the ifc file to IFC2RAD.txt file. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After pritinting write it to file, like this:

```
IfcFile = open('ifc2.ifc', 'r')

#defines the string 
IfcColourData = re.compile('ifccolourrgb', re.IGNORECASE)

f = open('IFC2RAD.txt', 'w')    # opne file to write here

for RadColourData in IfcFile:
    if re.search(IfcColourData, RadColourData):
        print(RadColourData)
        f.write(RadColourData)      # write here to file
IfcFile.close()       
f.close()
```